# Inconsistent classNames between server and client rendered components

Tags: material-ui

I have an issue whereby my client rendered components class names (custom class names created with makeStyles) are of the format `jss1234`, however when rendering on the server they are of the format `makeStyles-name-1234`. Causing issues when I then hydrate.

I have followed the server side set up here: https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/#handling-the-request pretty much to the letter.

My client entry point looks something like:

```
const Main = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // clean up any server side generated styles
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={ theme }>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.hydrate(<Main />, root);
```

This is only an issue in production and I have ensured that both my server and client side code have `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`.

I don't mind which format my classnames are, as long as they are consistent. I have tried using the StylesProvider and creating a new generateClassName function to force one way or the other, but it just doesn't seem to work. Client is always `jss` and server is always `makeStyles` prefixed.

Is there any other method of configuring this that I am missing?

thanks, in advance, I will update the question with any more information as I find it.

**Update**

On closer inspection it looks as though I cannot override the generateClassName function, I pass one in and a function is generated, but its not that one that gets called.

I have the following:

```
  const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({ disableGlobal: true });
  const css = new ServerStyleSheets({ generateClassName });

  const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    css.collect(
      <StylesProvider generateClassName={ generateClassName }>
        <ThemeProvider theme={ theme }>
          ...
```

and in my client:

```
  const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({ disableGlobal: true });

  return (
    <StylesProvider generateClassName={ generateClassName }>
      <ThemeProvider theme={ theme }>
      ...
```

But the disableGlobal never takes effect, it looks as though it never actually uses this function. I must be missing some configuration, however I find the documentation about this stuff a little fragmented and it seems to suggest I wouldn't need to use StylesProvider on the server with the new API.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem. I follow the exact tutorial in  https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/#handling-the-request. The development build works fine, but when running the production build on node, the server side rendering used development class names, causing a class mismatch on hydration.

I solved this by including the NODE_ENV enviroment variable on node bootstrap on production server.

```
NODE_ENV=production node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out this was indeed an issue with NODE_ENV.

In my case I was compiling my client code with webpack, but not the external node modules (using webpack nodeExternals). The command to do this was something like:

`NODE_ENV=production webpack ... && node server.js`

changing these to seperate npm tasks or something like:

`NODE_ENV=production webpack ... && NODE_ENV=production node server.js`

This solved the issue and I have been able to remove the StylesProvider from my code, as it is not needed with the new MUI v4 API.

Thanks and keep up the good work.

Comment: Hi @jamiedust, Can you please provide more info as to where this command is to be executed or point to documentations?

Comment: This was in my `npm scripts` defined in `package.json`, you just need to ensure that when the server code runs the `NODE_ENV` variable is set correctly.

In my case I had not done this correctly as I did not realise that defining an environment variable inline is not passed along an and (&&) chain.

Comment: console.log the value of process.env.NODE_ENV in both your client side and server side render code. They should be the same value.