# Material-UI TextField's style is missing after production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I added `SSR` and `Material-UI` with react on my project.
It is ok when I build with development mode.
However Material-UI TextFields looks weired after I built with production mode.

[image: production build]

[image: development build]

I found style of class named `PrivateNotchedOutline-root-78` is missing after production build.

How can I solve this problem..?

github repo about this project :
https://github.com/jeean/mui_test

Comment: As mentioned in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/api/), the class names change during production. There is a specific key for both development and production to generate the class names. Because of that, you should not rely on these names at all, since they can also change between material-ui versions. Bit since the base style is gone, you should try to wrap your app in a mui theme provider . But it seems like, your style data is not correctly passed down from the server to the client.

Comment: You should take a look at the docs for server side Rendering: https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/

Comment: @Domino987 thank you for comment. Theme provider from the document didnt work.

Comment: I found It renders correctly when I remove webpack's external option `externals: [nodeExternals()]`. I still coudln't figure out why nodeExternals makes this problem.

Comment: `NODE_ENV = production node server.js` was solution!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186602/inconsistent-classnames-between-server-and-client-rendered-components/57198525#57198525